# I have a variable with a list of values that I would like to loop through & print value with a comment

Tags: bash, comments

Using #!/bin/bash

```
variable
----------
abc123
abc1245
abc2390
```

I would like to do the following:

```
for r in "$variable" ; do
 if [ [ "$variable" != ""] ] ; then
     echo "$r OK"
   continue
 fi
done
```

I would like to output the value (i.e. each line) with a comment, "OK" as shown below

```
abc123 OK
abc1245 OK
abc2390 OK
```

however, the script above outputs this

```
abc123
abc1245
abc2390 OK
```

Thoughts?

Comment: The `continue` is pointless.  The notation `if [ [ "$variable" != ""] ]` is erroneous.  Either you want: `if [[ "$variable" != "" ]]` or you want `if [ "$variable" != "" ]` — in both cases, separating the empty string from the `]`.  It's odd to iterate on `r` and then test `"$variable"` in the loop.  Using `"$variable"` in the `for` means the loop iterates just once (which is why you get the one OK at the end of the only output).  You probably want `for r in $variable` so that the value is split at white space, but be cautious about that.  If you'd run `bash -x script.sh`, you'd see all this.

Comment: Makes sense. thanks for explaining

Answer (score 0):

almost!

take the quotes off of `$variable`, otherwise it's treated as a single value:

```
for r in $variable ; do
  if [ "$r" != "" ] ; then
    echo "$r OK"
  fi
done
```

(also, your `if` was checking `$variable` instead of `$r` each time, and there was a superfluous `continue`.)

here's an easier way though:

```
echo "$variable" | awk '/./{print $0, "OK"}'
```

that prints every non-blank line plus with an `OK` after.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!